# full screen contentPanel ext gwt

Tags: gwt, resolution, extjs

I need to implement full screen ContentPanel in ext gwt. I use setSize method, but as params I can specify only resolution.

```
public class HomePage extends ContentPanel {

public HomePage() {

    setSize(1024,768);
```

I want to have panel that will fill all window in each browser with different monitor resolution. So how can I use setsize method to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the size, maybe try setting a layout that will expand. Maybe something like this (hasn't been tested):

```
setLayout(new FitLayout());
```

Answer (score 1):

In GXT 3, I used:

```
private static final int WIDTH_SCREEN = XDOM.getViewportWidth();
private static final int HEIGTH_SCREEN = XDOM.getViewportHeight();
```

And after that use `setWidth, setHeight`