# Resizing the GXT application on different screen resolutions

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have an application which is built on BorderLayout (following the examples) having 3 content panels with names east, west and center

Within these content panels i have placed various content panels / layout containers having fixed width and height. Many of these child containers have absolute layout. The application is built and the widgets are positioned keeping in mind 1024x768 screen resolution

Now, If this app is opened on a screen having wider resolution say 1280x900 etc, it looks odd leaving out too many white spaces around their area.

I tried autoHeight property of the containers which is removing the vertical scrolling while used (specially with tree panel, which i am using in west panel)

Please help me with any examples / tips to make my application get adjusted to whatever resolution its being displayed on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a javascript function to get the screen resolution and adapt your dimension after

```
public static native int getScreenWidth() /*-{ 
      return $wnd.screen.width;
   }-*/;
```

the same goes for height;

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392889/full-screen-contentpanel-ext-gwt) may help too.

Comment: Thanks @Catalin for your help. Getting window size OR using FillLayout did work but I had to do a lot of setSize calls on many containers. What I found out later is using ViewPort container.

When I used ViewPort as the base container and applied BorderLayout to it, all the east, west and center containers seemed to take up the whole browser space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GWT `RootPanel` methods:

```
int height = RootPanel.get().getOffsetHeight();
int width = RootPanel.get().getOffsetWidth();
```